# How to check that types are the same?

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to check if 2 types are the same one. I expected

```
export type AreSame<T, U, R> = T extends U ? U extends T ? R : never : never;
```

to work, but actually it [fails](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=53&pln=6&pc=56#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCVgGUCGBbYAHgBUAaOAVXICUA+OAXjmLlBmADsATAZ0rgD8-Np17NBcanABccDsABuwKDLmLlAbgCwAKF1IU6Ruky4ChAIzkrcAPIAjAFbAAxjHpxPXrwHofdp1cYfWRUACFjDGx8IhsAJnIHZzcPb28-NSUoEMMAYUjTGMtyDgBXPHtlRMCUtIz5LJzUABEC6PMbCzgAHzgEgOT3NLgMpKC4AFo4AHcAC0QBRaa4AFE2s1ievustgGZqwY9RmvgpuYWlnQNUADF1oq7e-sftgaCj-zG3XSA) on unions:

```
type A = AreSame<1, 1, Object>          // Object
type B = AreSame<1, 2, Object>          // never
type C = AreSame<1, number, Object>     // never
type D = AreSame<1, 1 | 2, Object>      // Object - why???
type E = AreSame<1 | 2, 1 | 3, Object>  // Object - why???
type F = AreSame<1 | 2, 1 | 2, Object>  // Object
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just taking a guess here, but if we consider a union to be similar to a logical or, this would make sense.

Let me try to pseudo code the steps it takes for the question..

```js
1 extends (1|2) ? (1|2) extends 1 ? Object : never : never // becomes ->
(1 extends 1 || 1 extends 2) ? (1 extends 1 || 2 extends 1) ? : Object : never : never
```

I would consider checking the typescript code to check how it exactly works..

EDIT: To solve this problem, I found [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024) in the typescript repository

The best solution there is this:

```js
export type Equals<X, Y> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;
```

Maybe you can adjust that for your case? Hope that helps :)

Comment: It may be the reason, but what I should change to make it working like I need?

Answer (score 4):

Your conditional types are accidentally [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).  That means it ends up splitting up the unions, evaluating the type for each member, and unioning them back together.  Please familiarize yourself with that documentation, because it's important.  If you have a type like `type G<T> = T extends U ? X : Y` where `T` is a "naked" type parameter (so it's `T extends` and not `SomethingWith<T> extends`) then it will distribute.  Sometimes this is what you want.  Right now it's not.

The easiest way to turn off distributive conditional types is by "clothing" the naked type parameter: turn `T extends U ? X : Y` into `[T] extends [U] ? X : Y`.  So:

```
export type AreSame<T, U, R> = [T] extends [U] ? [U] extends [T] ? R : never : never;

type A = AreSame<1, 1, Object>          // Object
type B = AreSame<1, 2, Object>          // never
type C = AreSame<1, number, Object>     // never
type D = AreSame<1, 1 | 2, Object>      // never
type E = AreSame<1 | 2, 1 | 3, Object>  // never
type F = AreSame<1 | 2, 1 | 2, Object>  // Object
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCVgGUCGBbYAHgBUAaOAVXICUA+OAXjgG1iBdOUGYAOwBMAziwocA-MI5degluzjjqcAFxwewAG7Aoy1Rq0BuALAAoE0hTpG6TLgKEAjOUdwA8gCMAVsADGMenADAwIB6YNdPHxgzZFQAISsMbHwiZwAmcncvX38goNDdTShoiwBhBJtkh3IeAFc8Ny0MiOzc-LVC4tQAEXKku2d7OAAfOHTwrL9cuDa9IuNzVABRXtsU4dGndYBmJon-GY75mLgAMRXKwZGxy43xyP2wzMiTIA)