# Typescript: Why A extends B and B extends A does not mean A Equal B?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to find a generic type to judge if type A equal type B.

Something like this.

```
type Equal<A, B> = A === B ? true : false;
```

But there is no `===` operator in typescript.

I have checked this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024) and find a good implementation.

Let us see some types first.

```
type test18 = boolean extends false ? true : false; // return false as expected
type test19 = false extends boolean ? true : false; // return true as expected
type test20 = false extends boolean ? boolean extends false ? true : false : false; // return false as expected
type test21 = boolean extends false ? false extends boolean ? true : false : false; // return false as expected
```

**My question is that why this code does not work?**

```
type Equal<A, B> = A extends B ? B extends A ? true : false : false;

type test1 = Equal<boolean, false>; // why return boolean rather than false
```

Why test1 is `boolean` rather than `false`.

And there are other cases also not work.

```
type test9 = Equal<any, string>; // boolean
type test10 = Equal<any, number>; // boolean
type test12 = Equal<string | number, number>; // boolean
type test121 = Equal<string | number, string | number>; // boolean
type test125 = Equal<{x:number} | {y:string}, {x:number} | {y:string}>; // boolean

type test13 = Equal<never, number>; // never
type test14 = Equal<never, never>; // never
type test15 = Equal<never, unknown>; // never
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/zh/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsA8BBANFAQgPigF4oMoIAPYCAOwBMBnPKAfmcuvqbLamACcE0AFxQAZqgYjxkiAG4AUEtCQ+EBsACMxWIlRoARgHsjKCEho4JKKfkUKV0ahoBMO+MnQChV2XeXgTurAAMzuel6CEDjeEP4OgWoaACzhnmjWUr42cfaOScAArGn6mtm2eYnOwABsJehlUDQIALYGEPzx+dUA7PVojRr8AJY0AOZdVcEAHP0A5JpzOEOjE5Wq1QCc-RYgywKrkxvBmgAMOzR7Ta3tnetBGpraJB76K+M4zW0dRw9abi8Imh3mMoAAfa7ffifG4-RTdE4uZ66dIg8GQ277EbjdFfW7+BGPFxhQHpADeFGEeI6AF8oAAyKBkkDCEE0nAUqmw-g0glTImpUn6TnUnkMpkstkcymiumM5msg7jXnw-n-YpC9Ai7l0iEKqVMmU69H6pVjFUBY6PEko-Q0CAANw6MKhvwKmkFtvQ9qd0Kajrhlr+mg1XrQPudUAQNAA1jQjAB3Ghu6qaOqatDRuOJyxR2PxpMpk59DNZgu5iN3JQKIA)

Comment: I don't know what is the relation between OOP and this question. Could you explain more?

Comment: If TS is interpreting `boolean = true | false` then ["distributivity" of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) could explain this. Hence why the solution in the linked GH issue uses the square brackets the documentation recommends to avoid distributivity.

Comment: @HTNW I almost get the sense. 

But why test20 and test21 work as expected. Test20 and test21 are in the question description.

Comment: @HTNW I guess `distributive` only works on a generic type. So test20 and test21 work right.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58564260/2887218) to the linked question for more information